# SQL String error? No Such Column

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 in my c++ program and am trying to run an SQL string in the 
sqlite3_get_table function.

Here's my sql string.

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=test_table;
```

I keep getting the error "no such column "test_table"" .

All I am trying to do is confirm the existence of a table in my database. That's all.
Any clues as to what's wrong with my string.

Comment: Your posting is ambiguous about the use of quotes in the string. What you posted is not a valid C++ string (because the double-quotes are not escaped), nor is it a valid SQL string because it cannot start with a double-quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQLite double quotes ('`"`') is the identifier-escape character, so assuming this is your SQL (raw SQL, nothing to do with C++):

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    sqlite_master
WHERE
    type = 'table'
    AND
    name = "test_table;"
```

Is equivalent to:

```
...
name = test_table
```

...which obviously isn't what you want.

You should use single-quoted strings in SQL, and the statement-terminating semicolon should go at the very end:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    sqlite_master
WHERE
    type = 'table'
    AND
    name = 'test_table';
```